# Name this sound effect

Tags: sound-effects, sound-effects-recording, effect

**TLDR:** Its loop pedal effect that we are talking about.

Guyz have been pulling my hairs for quiet a while, just cant figure out what this effect is called or what term should I use to Google, for any plugins for flstudio or similar to get this effect. I have exhausted all my imaginations by searching "revervbation","reverbating echo", "continious echo loop"...

**Effect:** The continuous echo this guy is creating.

PS: I know that he is using a dedicated hardware for it, but I am quiet sure there exists a software for the similar effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

he's using a loop pedal.  if you're looking for a plugin for that try googling "live looping plugin"  or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I've got an app in the iPad for that: **[Loopy](http://loopyapp.com/)**

Much more modern and convenient... The pedal is optional you just need your fingers =)

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible he's using something like Ableton Live to record the samples as he performs and play them back as he continues to perform.